# Conditionally remove and replace a HTML form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Good Day,
I'm trying to figure out how to completely remove a form element from the DOM and replace it back while users select a YES or No from a dropdown. Below is my HTML Code;

```
<label for="show_form"><?php _e('Show Form?', 'text-domain'); ?></label>
<select class="form-control" id="show_form" name="show_form">
    <option value="YES">YES</option>
    <option value="NO">NO</option>
</select>
<form id="co_form" method="post" action="">
    <!-- My Form Codes here -->
</form>
```

i was able to remove the form using the below jQuery Code;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#show_form').on('change', yes_or_no_toggle);
});

function yes_or_no_toggle() {
    var getYesNOSelect = jQuery("#show_form option:selected").val();

    if ( getYesNOSelect == 'NO' ) {
        var clone = $('#co_form').clone();
        jQuery('#co_form').remove();
    } else {
        jQuery('body').append(clone);
    }

}
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong but it removes the form which works already but when i select YES, nothing  happens

I would like the form to reappear when users select YES and it should be removed and replaced depending on if the user select YES/NO. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Take that clone varible out of if block. Below example, it is out of function scope and it should work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#show_form').on('change', yes_or_no_toggle);
});

var formObj = $('#co_form').clone();
function yes_or_no_toggle() {
    var getYesNOSelect = jQuery("#show_form option:selected").val();

    if ( getYesNOSelect == 'NO' ) {

        jQuery('#co_form').remove();
    } else {
        jQuery('body').append(formObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working ... how do i even check if the whole form has been cloned ... just to be sure the clone works

Comment: https://jsbin.com/tixodufusa/edit?html,js,output here is the link that shows the working example. You can put Console.log(formObj) into your code to print it to console and check what is assigned to that variable

Comment: Where should i add the console log? as when i added it directly under the variable, i got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Console is not defined
    at (index):384` .. Sorry if this is a stupid question but please where should i add the console error

Comment: I am just writing usin my phone it will probably console.log you can google it

Comment: I have done it and i got this `w.fn.init [form#co_form, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]` in my console

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the cloned form outside of the change handler. After you remove it it doesn't exist the next time `yes_or_no_toggle()` gets called

Try something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  // store clone on page load
  var clone = $('#co_form').clone();

  jQuery('#show_form').on('change', yes_or_no_toggle);

  function yes_or_no_toggle() {
    var getYesNOSelect = jQuery(this).val();

    if (getYesNOSelect == 'NO') {
      jQuery('#co_form').remove();
    } else {
      jQuery('body').append(clone);
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: I have moved it and yet its not bringing it back. it removes but doesn't bring it back

Comment: Note if you do this multiple times should do `jQuery('body').append(clone.clone());`

Comment: I'm getting a console error after doing exactly what you did here [link](jsfiddle.net/ya04z8jv) `Uncaught ReferenceError: clone is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.yes_or_no_toggle ((index):391)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=4.9.9:2)
    at HTMLSelectElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=4.9.9:2)`

Comment: You probably didn't move the function inside `ready` as I did

Comment: Please discard my above error, i have fixed that by moving my toggle IF into the function containing the var clone and no more error but its not showing the form when i switch back to YES. is there a specific script i need to load on the page for this to work?

Comment: Edit my demo so it reproduces the problem

Comment: Also...can you just hide/show the form instead? Would be much simpler

Comment: I have edited your code ... by copying what i did already in my code and replacing with yours and changing some the ID of the select to match the code and it worked. I;'m actually doing this code inside of wordpress, is there a jQuery API i need to load on the page to make this work? I don't want to use hide/show because a tech savvy user can manipulate it by changing `display:none` to `display:block;` (since this is a client side thing)

Comment: Is there any ajax being used to load that form originally?

Comment: Nope, just jQuery for form behavior and PHP for validation. Can't write Ajax just yet